# can't rename HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive

My son's mac running 10.11 has the hard drive named this
curie HD"""""""""""
copying and pasting reveals lots of spaces after the sequence of " characters.
I can't rename the HD in Finder. Every attempt fails with "The name "Curie HD""""     " can't be used. Try using a name with fewer characters or with no punctuation marks.

Note that the applications folder also shows nothing, same with documents etc. Spotlight reveals no apps. However, Finder -> Go To works.

Disk utility reports no errors.

in the shell, the HD is not visible in volumes

diskutil cs list looks like this the screen shot:

[image]

trying as root:

```
# diskutil rename / curieHD
```

get "Volume must be mounted" 
I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The FileVault volume has to be unlocked and mounted.

Then try the following:

1. Get the device node of the falsely labeled volume:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```
2. Rename the device with:

   ```
   diskutil rename /dev/diskX NewName
   ```

   with diskX: the device node found earlier (probably disk1)

Comment: diskutil /dev/disk0 newname produces Volume must be mounted

Comment: @TimRichardson The device node is with certainty **not** disk0. Depending how you booted your Mac it's probably either disk1 or disk2. Additionally you have to unlock the FileVault volume before executing `diskutil list`! You may also check `diskutil cs list`. The disk in your screenshot shows disk1 for the logical volume. This may change if you boot to Recovery Mode!